# Can I use Anymote Protocol send keyevent to Android TV

Tags: protocols, google-tv, android-tv, anymote

The Anymote Protocol is used for Google TV, but I don't know if it will be usefull on Android TV. Thanks!!!

Comment: no, i have not android TV @Palak

Comment: I am also looking for same...can you please post the answer you got if any?

Answer (score 1):

No, the Android TV does not implement the Anymote protocol. Google not made public yet a documentation / API for controlling Android TV boxes the same way we could control Google TV.

Comment: Thanks,  do you know the documentation / API for controll Android TV?